# Group by clause nested selects statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling to get this code to work, what I want to do is select numerous columns names and then group the results by two other columns in the same table.

But I just cannot seem to get the syntax correct, so anyone with a lot more sql server experience than me who can help me with this would be appreciated.

What I'm looking for is to return non duplicate results based on latitude,longitude

Actual code

```
SELECT    [CityName]                         AS CityName,  
          ISNULL(NULLIF([CountyName],''),'') AS CountyName,
          [CityLatitude]                     AS Latitude,
          [CityLongitude]                    AS Longitude
    FROM [dbo].[tblCityLatitudeLongitudes]
          WHERE [CountryName] = @Country

    ORDER by [CityName] ASC
    OFFSET @OffSet ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

I have tried various other ways, and below is my last attempt but still throws an error

```
SELECT    a.CityName                       AS CityName,  
          ISNULL(NULLIF(a.CountyName,''),'')  AS CountyName,
          a.CityLatitude                   AS Latitude,
          a.CityLongitude                  AS Longitude 
          FROM
 (SELECT b.CityLatitude,b.CityLongitude
 FROM  tblCityLatitudeLongitudes b
 WHERE b.CountryName = 'united kingdom'
GROUP BY b.CityLatitude,b.CityLongitude) a
```

Errors

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Invalid column name 'CityName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'CountyName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'CountyName'.
```

Comment: You might add the sheam of `tblCityLatitudeLongitudes`

Comment: @bummi not sure what you mean

Comment: Side note: the `NULLIF` in `ISNULL(NULLIF([CountyName],''),'')` seems redundant, `ISNULL([CountyName],'')` would give you same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do group by on other columns and get max latitude and longitude.

```
  SELECT    a.CityName                       AS CityName,  
         ISNULL(NULLIF(a.CountyName,''),'')  AS CountyName,
      Max(a.CityLatitude    )               AS Latitude,
      Max(a.CityLongitude      )            AS Longitude 
      FROM
    tblCityLatitudeLongitudes a
    WHERE a.CountryName = 'united kingdom'
    GROUP BY CityName, ISNULL(NULLIF(a.CountyName,''),'') 
ORDER by [CityName] ASC
OFFSET @OffSet ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: does not work error Column 'tblCityLatitudeLongitudes.CountyName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @george phillipson, it was typo corrected it, group by should be on countyname, I had country name, try it now

Comment: RADAR you will need to `GROUP BY a.CityName  , ISNULL(NULLIF(a.CountyName,''),'')` to get this working.

Comment: @M.Ali thanks, looks like  shopping and typing at same time is dangerous ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CityName
      ,CountyName
      ,Latitude
      ,Longitude
FROM (
    SELECT    [CityName]                         AS CityName,  
              ISNULL(NULLIF([CountyName],''),'') AS CountyName,
              [CityLatitude]                     AS Latitude,
              [CityLongitude]                    AS Longitude,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CityLatitude],[CityLongitude] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))rn 
    FROM [dbo].[tblCityLatitudeLongitudes]
    WHERE [CountryName] = @Country
    )A
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER by [CityName] ASC
OFFSET @OffSet ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: cannot seem to get  OFFSET OffSet ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY to work, not sure where it needs to go

Comment: You dont have OFFSET in Sql server 2008 , it was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I'm using sql 2012, entered wrong tags

Comment: You should be able to just add ORDER BY and FETCH clause at the end of this outer query.